# Bootstrap column nesting

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following column layout in Bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This creates a 1/3rd column on the left and a 2/3rds column on the left.

[image]

What I actually want is to layer the columns so the left (col-sm-4) column would sit on top of a col-sm-12 column, something like this:

[image]

Is this possible with Bootstrap's grid?

Comment: Either use `absolute positioning` or, add the `sm-4` inside the `sm-12` and `remove padding` on the `sm-12` if there is any, and `remove any margin` on the `sm-4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely nest columns, but be sure to include a new `.row` element for each level of nesting. This avoids having to add additional classes and CSS as previous answers have suggested.

What most people don't realize is that Bootstrap's `.row` and `.col-*` classes work together to clear floats and even out padding.

**No CSS needed:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- 12 col element -->
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <!-- additional row element -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- 4 col element -->
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
.outer {
  padding: 0;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 outer">
          <div class="col-sm-4 inner">
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should I still be able to add stuff to the remaining section of the col-sm-12, for example if I wanted a col-sm-8 as well as the col-sm-4?

Comment: Yeah absolutely - its just normal grid behavior but added padding and margin styles to sit them flush

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It's bad form to have a bootstrap column class as the direct descendent of another column element. Please see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I came up with:

```css
.col-sm-12 {
  background: #ddd;
}

.your-bs-override {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  background: #000;
  height: 100px; // just to demo better
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          inner col-sm-12
          <div class="col-sm-4 your-bs-override">
            inner col-sm-4
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Understanding the context may help refine the answers provided so far.

Comment: It's bad form to have a bootstrap column class as the direct descendent of another column element. Please see my answer.

Comment: Aware of that, thanks. Despite my margin adjustments mimicking a div.row - the lightbulb didn't come on to simply adjust the HTML. Bad dog.