# Bootstrap Form Inputs Break When Screen is Large

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, input, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I can't figure out why form inputs in this boostrap form are breaking when I extend the screen size to 'large'. I'm trying to get the large version to basically be identical to the medium version. I'm not sure what's breaking the layout.

Here's the codepen: 
http://codepen.io/ctdvnprt/pen/JWaELE?editors=1000

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var steps_link = $('div.steps div a'),
    steps_contents = $('.step-content'),
    nexts = $('.nextBtn');

  steps_contents.hide();

  steps_link.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
      $item = $(this);

    if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
      steps_link.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
      $item.addClass('btn-primary');
      steps_contents.hide();
      $target.show();
      $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
    }
  });

  nexts.click(function() {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".step-content"),
      curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
      nextwizard = $('div.steps div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
      curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
      isValid = true;

    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");

    for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
      if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
        isValid = false;
        $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
      }
    }

    if (isValid) {
      nextwizard.removeClass('disabled').trigger('click');
    }
  });

  $('div.steps div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');

});
```

```css
body{
  font-family:'Calibri';
  font-size:14px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}


.wizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.wizard-row {
    display:table-row;
 
}
.wizard {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
   margin-top:-50px;
}

.wizard-step .disabled{
    opacity:1;
    color:#ccc;
    background:#efefef;
}
.wizard-row:before {
    top:30px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;
}
.wizard-step {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.btn-circle {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    line-height:44px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: #00467f;
}

.nextBtn {
    background-color: #007dc3;
    border-color: #007dc3; 
}

.nextBtn:hover {
    background-color: #006ba5;
    border-color: #006ba5; 
}

.btn-default {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-success {
    background-color: #78a025;
    border-color: #78a025; 
}

.btn-success:hover, .btn-success:active {
    background-color: #6a8921;
    border-color: #6a8921; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="well" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <div class="wizard col-lg-12">
      <div class="wizard-row steps">
        <div class="wizard-step">
          <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
          <p>Personal Information</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wizard-step">
          <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle disabled">2</a>
          <p>Your Interests</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wizard-step">
          <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle disabled">3</a>
          <p>Additional Information</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend></legend>
      <form role="form" action="" method="post">
        <div class="row step-content" id="step-1">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
              <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row step-content" id="step-2">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
              <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row step-content" id="step-3">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See this answer with regards to using bootstrap columns and rows. May be related to your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35342238/5351721

Comment: Set two columns and make input width 100% and the button as btn-block,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the width of the fieldset. Add the information that width is 100% like that `<fieldset style="width: 100%">`

Or you can delete the fieldset tag. You don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it' better to create two columns and separete input from your button. The set input width 100% and button  class as `btn-block` and remove pull-right in  the class. I hope it will help.

```
<div class="row step-content" id="step-1">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
      <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" width="100%" />
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-block" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```